# Blender to Aftereffects

Tags: export, compositing-nodes

On After Effect i have my png sequence (Blender Cube) and i'd want to mix on my video.

How can I do that?  I can see either only the video or only the cube.

The cube is png but i see the background black https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e8bOYkshku9GpN6cLOXVxEcgxEcILY2T

Answer (score 0):

RENDER tab property> FILM tab, mark "make transparent".